How to make reference to another organization task in vscode?
I have two organizations the code I am managing is a side organization that differs from the main one.
For convenience let's say:
MyCode - Org1
Backlog task - Org2
Both organizations are on dev.azure.com
So I would like to commit my code (located in Org1) with a comment in VSCode using task ID from Org2.
Is it possible?
I do see some options in tasks links on Org1 called "Remote Related":



I would like to commit my code (located in Org1) with a comment in VSCode using task ID from Org2. Is it possible? I do see some options in tasks links on Org1 called "Remote Related".

It is not supported to link a commit to a workitem with the Remote Related link type. This link type only supports to link workitems form the organizations that use the same Microsoft Entra ID. You can check the Link work items to remote work items for more details.

If you need this feature, you can request a feature for Azure DevOps here to help the feature better.
